# How do you increment a integer passed from a argument that accepts strings

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I created a method that creates a Html element 4 times and

```
public IHtmlString customHtml(string htmlCode){
    for(int i = 0; i<4 i++){
        htmlCode += htmlCode;
    }
    return new HtmlString(htmlCode);
 }
```

When this method is called 4 times the `int someNumber` is concatenated with the string and I would like it to increment 1-4

```
int someNumber = 1;

@customHtml("<div>"+(someNumber++)+"<div>")
```

With resulting Html being:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Instead I get this:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>1</div>
```

The element wont always be a `<div>` and the number is not always passed through with the string and the int can start at any number not just 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in your htmlCode as a template that will be formatted later:

Your razor syntax becomes this:

```
@customHtml("<div>{0}<div>")
```

And your method looks like this:

```
public IHtmlString customHtml(string htmlCode){
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 1; i<=4; i++){
        sb.AppendFormat(htmlCode, i);
    }
    return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
 }
```

The reason your original attempt doesn't work is because you are passing a string to your method. You're not passing an expression. This means that you are passing the exact string `"<div>1</div>"` to your method and then your method just writes that string out four times.

**Addendum:**

Now, if you really want to structure it like your example, you could do this:

```
public IHtmlString customHtml(Func<string> s)  {
  var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 1; i<=4; i++){
        sb.Append(s());
    }
    return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

Then, your Razor syntax looks like this:

```
int someNumber = 1;
@customHtml(() => "<div>" + someNumber++ + "</div>").Dump();
```

Either of these solutions give you the same results: `<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the parameter from your method and use the variable you're iterating over when you generate the html markup.

```
var htmlCode = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    htmlCode.AppendFormat("<div>{0}</div>", i);
}
return new HtmlString(htmlCode.ToString());
```

If it's really necessary to pass the html into this method, maybe because the markup you're "repeating" changes, then we'll need to modify this.

Comment: The method wont always have a integer and more than one element than just the div tag can be passed

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing...

```
int someNumber = 1;
@customHtml("<div>"+(someNumber++)+"<div>")
```

with

```
int someNumber = 0;
@customHtml("<div>"+(++someNumber)+"<div>");
```

Strangely enough, that has worked for me countless times when presented with incremental/decremental issues.

Comment: It only increments it once for me

Comment: That's very weird. No reason why int should increment as expected. Have you tried incrementing it OUTSIDE of the @customHtml() ?

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by outside the @customHtml()

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just send two parameters?

```
public IHtmlString customHtml(string htmlCode, int someNumber){
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = someNumber; I < someNumber + 4; i++){
        sb.AppendFormat(htmlCode, i);
    }
    return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
@customHtml("<div>{0}<div>", someNumber)
```